# Jmeter: Active Browser Tab

Tags: jmeter

Running Jmeter on a service whereby there is Duo MFA (with MFA being bypassed). The Duo MFA page bypasses only if in active browser tab. Would there be a way for Jmeter to mimic active browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your "Duo MFA" (whatever it is) is using [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for detecting whether its being run in the browser and maybe even by human (i.e. it has [bot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_bot)-detecting heuristics)

As per JMeter project main page:

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So I don't think that it is possible to "bypass" this real browser check without kicking off a real browser.

The options are in:

1. Ask your application developers/devops/whoever is responsible for the infrastructure to turn off this MFA as your test should focus on your application and not on external resources/dependencies
2. Use a real browser for bypassing it, for example [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) plugin provides JMeter integration with Selenium browser automation framework. Once you are let in you can transfer cookies from the browser into JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and continue using normal HTTP Request samplers
3. Try to reverse this "browser" check by inspecting the traffic which is going back and forth between your browser and this Duo MFA backend, if you'll manage to decrypt it - you should be able to replicate it so Duo MFA will think that you're using the browser, however I'm not sure that it's easily doable and legal